# Push view controller in navigation controller with interactive transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a view at the bottom of my view controller. How can I set up an interactive transition such that as I drag the view up vertically (perhaps using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`), another view controller is pushed up?

Similar to the default navigation controller behaviour with swiping left and right to push/pop, except this would be vertical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIDynamicAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicAnimator_Class/index.html) class for animation.

You will have to use [AttachmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAttachmentBehavior_Class/) for such kind of attachment animation. It's subclass of `UIDynamicAnimator`. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938813/animate-a-view-on-key-window-while-dragging-another-view-with-uilongpressgesture/29939180#29939180). It might help you.